# MacBook Pro - Which color profile is more realistic and like life?

Tags: color

On the MacBook Pro, which color profile is more realistic and life like?
Color LCD or SMPTE RP 431-2-2007 DCI (P3)?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a colorimeter to make an accurate profile, the best profile is the default profile, which will depend on your exact MBP model.

In System Prefs > Displays > Colour check the box for 'Show profiles for this display only' which will include system defaults plus any custom profiles specifically made for that display.

Answer (score 1):

> Which color profile is more realistic and like life?

There is no way to know without calibrating your display. If color accuracy matters, buy a colorimeter. Older models are cheap and better than not calibrating at all.

According to [How to Color Calibrate Your Mac’s Display](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/color-calibrating-your-macs-display/), the default profile is probably Color LCD, but depends on the specific display model.